# How to Create OAuth Client ID?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-client, google-developers-console

I am trying to run this [github project](https://github.com/luispadron/YouTube-Subscription-Importer.git).
For this I need to create credentials and OAuth Client Id.
When I click to create. After selecting web applications and typing the name I see authorised javascript and authorised redirect uri.

So what should I enter there because I tried with keeping both fields empty. But I got error saying **no redirect url found for client id**

Please help me.
I am using Developer Console for first time can't find any help on internet. This site is my last hope.

**I did as said in [comment].[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61349819/13338404)**
Here is what I got in Linux shell and the error i received on redirected url opened webpage.

**Linux Shell Message**

```html
/YouTube-Subscription-Importer/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access subscribe.py-oauth2.json: No such file or directory
warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))
Your browser has been opened to visit:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=1069660256195-n8adm0dmi70v29i55hcfblftle09hb5n.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&access_type=offline&response_type=code
If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter
--noauth_local_webserver
```

[Snipe of what redirect url webpage said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjQMF.png)

**MOST IMPORTANT

> I am running this in windows bash.

Now tell me what to do next.

I just simply need a tutorial/how-to use guide for Google developer console credentials and OAuth Screen.

**

Comment: Did you register for an account already?

Comment: @AvivLo Yes. Why?

Comment: Just asking if you actually registered the credentials for use already.

Comment: yes but see the edited post. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You **need** the redirect URL, you will be redirected from Google OAuth Consent Screen to `https://REDIRECT_URL?code=AuthorizationCode`, you can just set it to `http://localhost`.

After creation, you can your find Client ID on the Credentials page.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: And what about authorised javascript uri?

Comment: @Neycerys you can leave it blank.